# Modelstate is not valid because the password im creating that is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I have been trying to debug why my modelstate is not valid, and when I go through debugging mode, I found out that the password field that I am trying to create is invalid and sometimes it becomes valid when I type in 'password' but most of the time when I randomly type in a password its invalid

I can to to debug and found out it was the password field as shown below
[image]

So I went onto my models to add some validation and it still wasn't able to add most of the times,

this is my appUser model where the password is a byte[],

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password, ErrorMessage ="password is not valid, has to be 8 characters long")]
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Role is required")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Invalid Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Job title is required")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department is required")]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public virtual Roles Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Booking { get; set; }
}
```

so what can I do to actually get rid of this bug?

Now I actually get this error and when I debug it said that the line int res == -1 when it should be 1.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: In your debug view (screenshot) what is the error message when you expand the `Errors` object?

Comment: The error shows “Hello123456” is an invalid Password

Comment: How come `Password` is a `byte[]` array and not a string? I'm not positive, but I feel like maybe that's (part of) the problem?

Comment: im using an entity framework type to generate that AppUser Model file

Comment: Pretty sure it failes because the property type is byte[] and your input is a string. The model state is checking for byte[] but "hello123456" is a string and will treat it as an invalid state. 

So you could change the property to be a string or convert your string to a byte array.

Comment: One More question, how do i insert HASHBYTE(‘(SHAH1)’, new_bytes)) in _dbcontext when inserting?

Comment: I have edited the question hope someone can help me out:(

Comment: _"how do i insert HASHBYTE(‘(SHAH1)’, new_bytes))"_ - you **don't**. You don't want to use SHA1, and you don't want to roll your own authentication system anyway. Use ASP.NET Identity.